# Make a CSS3 animation go backwards

Tags: css, animation

Hey guys I have a CSS3 animation which makes a pulsing effect using @keyframes animation .The problem is that the animation starts from 0% to 100% every time and I want to start from 0% to 100% and after 100% to 0% so the pulsing effect to have a continuity.The ball should increase to the full size and after slowly decrese to the initial size and after increase again and decrese and so on.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Pulse effect</title>
      <style>

         /*Border radius 50% to make it round */
         #circle{
           position: relative;
           width: 50px;
           height: 50px;
           border:2px solid red;
           border-radius: 50%;
          }

        #circle:after{
            content: '';
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            display: block;
            left:50%;
            margin-left: -10px;
            top:50%;
            margin-top: -10px;
            background-color: hsla(41, 97%, 47%,1);
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            /*Use keyframe animation to manipulate the effect */
            animation:pulseone 2s infinite;
        }


        @keyframes pulseone{
            /*Use SCALE value from TRANSFORM method to increse/decrese the x,y of the vector */
            0% {transform:scale(1,1);
                background-color: hsla(41,97%,47%,1);}
            /*25%{transform:scale(1.4,1.4);
                background-color: hsla(41,97%,47%,.9);} 
            50%{transform:scale(1.8,1.8);
                background-color:hsla(41,97%,47%,.8);}
            75%{trasform:scale(2.2,2.2);
                background-color: hsla(41,97%,47%,.7);}*/
            100%{transform:scale(2.5,2.5);
                background-color: hsla(41,97%,47%,.6);}
        }
        </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="circle"></div>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `animation-direction: alternate` to get the effect you are after.

In the shorthand you have, just add the `alternate` keyword:

```
animation:pulseone 2s infinite alternate;
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for.Thanks!But how can I get rid of that delay at the end?

Comment: At the end I have a short delay,how can I get rid of it?

Comment: What "delay" at the end? I created a fiddle with your code (https://jsfiddle.net/1LLmfr4r/) - do explain. Also please mark the answer as correct as it answers your initial question ;)

Comment: I figured it out.   animation:pulseone 2s infinite linear alternate(because alternate reverse time function so the ease-in becamed ease-out and that made that short delay at the end).Thanks again for the solution!